# Cron scripts in public folder issue

Tags: laravel, cron, public

Me and my team have placed our cron scripts in folder public and we have noticed that sometimes there are problems with cache and autoloading. For example, we can't use Eloquent as there is a problem with autoloading.

Is it ok to have cron scripts in public folder? If not, why?
And where we should place them?

Comment: What cron scripts are we talking about here, are they independent of Laravel? Placing them in the `public` folder makes them accessible "for everyone", if they know the name of your script, it can be run via webserver, which is probably not what you want, you also wouldn't want to call your cron scripts via `wget SCRIPTNAME.php` or something, skip the webserver. Set up [Laravel Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling)

Comment: They are cron scripts which do some data handling in database. They don't have input nor output.

Comment: Ideally you would create [Laravel console commands](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-commands) that take care of your data handling tasks and schedule those commands via Laravel Scheduling